# How to name the function of a thing differently than the thing itself?

Tags: domain-driven-design, naming

A *sensor* identified by the serial number “ABC1234” fulfills a measurement *function* identified by the name “Pressure sensor 7” in a production facility.

Within the production facility, nobody cares what the actual sensor fulfilling the *function* is. Actual sensors breaks on a regular basis and must be replaced.

When people refer to “Pressure sensor 7”, they mean the *function*, not the actual *sensor* device. But it is confusing because the name of the *function* (“Pressure sensor 7”) contains the word “sensor”. However, it is just so much easier to refer to the word “sensor”: “Register a new sensor” vs “Register a new measurement function”.

How can I make the user interface and the source code of the software controlling the facility unambiguous when it comes to express the concept of a *function* of a thing and not the actual thing (sensor, equipment, ...)?

I am missing vocabulary to differentiate the 2 concepts in a nice and user friendly way.

Comment: Finding suitable words is very specific to your particular context, so I don't think you will be able to get good answers here – you likely know far more about that context than us. And DDD primarily suggests using the words that the domain experts already use for that concept rather than inventing your own. Also, your question doesn't quite make it clear what the difference between a sensor and its function is for the purpose of your system.

Comment: "Pressure sensor 7" is a terrible name in the first place. Couldn't you name this after _what_ it is measuring? Eg, "Inlet pressure", "expansion chamber pressure", "pump #7 outlet pressure", etc.

Comment: @amon: sorry if I am not clear. _function_ is to _sensor_ what _role_ would be to _person_ in different context. Ex: A _person_ identified by the name "Alice" fulfills the _role_ identified by the name "Accounting Department Secretary" of a company. Customers don't care who the actual person is, they just want to deal with the "Accounting Department Secretary".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make the user interface and the source code of the software controlling the facility unambiguous when it comes to express the concept of a function of a thing and not the actual thing

By aligning the language with the context in which it is used.

It's *normal* that words like "sensor" mean different things to different people .  The key idea is to align the vocabulary in the code with the vocabulary of the people who use it.

That can mean that you have multiple different concepts in your code named "sensor", depending on which people are being served.  Namespaces are often used to distinguish between overlapping names from different contexts.